# Maximum number of pixels across a synthesized beam in an ALMA image?

Tags: observational-astronomy, telescope, data-analysis, interferometry, proto-planetary-disk

I have some ALMA data, from which I have created images using the TCLEAN task in CASA.

I understand that with this type of data, it is necessary to have at least 2 pixels across the FWHM of the synthesized beam, and a minimum of 3-5 is recommended.

**Is there an upper limit to the amount of pixels that should be used across the FWHM of the beam?** When using a large number of pixels across the beam, the images appear to be 'higher resolution' and are more aesthetically pleasing (see examples below). I realise that increasing the number of pixels doesn't *actually* improve the angular resolution of the images, but is there a particular reason not to use a larger number of pixels?

[image]